# Change website background with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, background

Okay, I want to change my website background with JavaScript. Ideally with a drop down menu, but for now, buttons.

This works:

```
function selText(test){
            var arr = document.getElementById(test).value;

            if (arr == 1){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images6.alphacoders.com/431/thumb-1920-431411.jpg')";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('btnim2')){
            document.body.style.background = 'none';
          }
      }



 <button id="btnim" value="1" onclick="selText(this.id)">text</button>
 <button id="btnim2" value="2" onclick="selText(this.id)">more text</button>
```

However, if I set my 'else if' to `arr == 2` and both buttons have the same id (`btnim`) it doesn't work, and I don't know why. I feel like I am missing something simple. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use arr==2 and id remains btnim2 of button 2 it will still work. You can't have same id's of many elements in webpage because it will confuse the javascript compiler to target which element.

```
function selText(test){
            var arr = document.getElementById(test).value;

            if (arr == 1){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images6.alphacoders.com/431/thumb-1920-431411.jpg')";
            }
            else if (arr==2){
            document.body.style.background = 'none';
          }
      }



 <button id="btnim" value="1" onclick="selText(this.id)">text</button>
 <button id="btnim2" value="2" onclick="selText(this.id)">more text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - it works :). Out of curiosity, is there a better way/alternative to using 'this.id'?

Comment: for what purpose you want to use id. There are many alternatives available to achieve the same objective. If you are asking the use of this.id in other scenarios then surely there are many uses. for that purpose visit https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to make this code work by passing the value of the button instead of id.

```
      function selText(test){
        var arr = test;

        if (arr == 1){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images6.alphacoders.com/431/thumb-1920-431411.jpg')";
        }
        else if (arr==2){
        document.body.style.background = 'none';
      }
  }
     <button id="btnim" value="1" onclick="selText(this.value)">text</button>
      <button id="btnim2" value="2" onclick="selText(this.value)">more text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the button itself as parameter instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selText(button){
        var arr = button.value;

        if (arr == 1){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images6.alphacoders.com/431/thumb-1920-431411.jpg')";
        } else if (arr == 2) {
            document.body.style.background = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>

<button id="btnim" value="1" onclick="selText(this)">text</button>
<button id="btnim2" value="2" onclick="selText(this)">more text</button>
```